# Dimension field in AX 2009 report dialog?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Under ax 2009 my requirement is to open a dialog box when I opens a report and it should show a drop down. So currently my drop down is SiteId from InventSite table. As show in code below.

```
public class ReportRun extends ObjectRun
{

    //Dialog
    DialogField dfSiteName;

    //Range
    InventSiteId siteName;

}

public boolean getFromDialog()
{
    ;

    siteName = dfSiteName.value();


    return true;
}

public Object dialog(Object _dialog)
{
    DialogRunBase dialog;
    FormDateControl siteNameControl;

    ;
    dialog = super(_dialog);
    dialog.caption("Sales Overview Range Dialog");
    dialog.addGroup("Selec Range");
    dfSiteName = dialog.addField(typeid(InventSiteId),"Site","Select Range");

    siteNameControl = dfSiteName.control();
    siteNameControl.mandatory(true);

    return dialog;
}
```

Everything is working fine with this code. Now instead  drop down of **SiteId** from InventSite table in dialog box I want drop down of **Dimension[1]** from InventSite table in dialog box. I am not able to do that. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you code work fine and you want to add only the `Dimension[1]` from `inventSite` table go to **AOT\Data Dictionary\Tables\InventSite\Field Groups\AutoLookup** here you there you will see `SiteId` and `Name` fields. You need to add new field then go to properties of this new field and select in property `DataField` the field that you need.

If you add this new field will be visible in all lookups for `InventSiteId` edt.